# Reorder a Dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to reorder some tables in r.

I extracted all the values from lmer() and confint() functions. Maybe there is another way to summarise the lmer()-results directly? (of various lmer-functions)

My tables look like this for example:

| a | loc_map_column | loc_stim_column | logVelocity | confidence_lower | confidence_upper | p_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | RA | NSR | -0.502600888 | -0.8253034 | -0.17987440 | 4.045130e-02 |
| 2 | RA | loc_stimLA | -0.034630279 | -0.4379126 | 0.36848580 | 2.084996e-29 |
| 3 | RA | loc_stimRA | -0.691259575 | -1.0801617 | -0.30230958 | 2.582846e-08 |
| 4 | LV | NSR | -0.182731047 | -0.8182401 | 0.46092692 | 5.829759e-01 |
| 5 | LV | loc_stimLV | -0.236928272 | -1.0013429 | 0.53562934 | 4.102663e-01 |
| 6 | LV | loc_stimRA | -0.913238563 | -1.6754108 | -0.13692249 | 2.867447e-27 |
| 7 | LV | loc_stimRV | -0.042520352 | -0.8544059 | 0.77911468 | 1.212858e-01 |
| 8 | LA | NSR | 0.007310606 | -0.3134600 | 0.32826335 | 9.650069e-01 |
| 9 | LA | loc_stimRA | -0.340983839 | -0.7728683 | 0.09108281 | 1.413686e-09 |
| 10 | RV | NSR | -0.351529452 | -0.8852501 | 0.18298935 | 2.710587e-01 |
| 11 | RV | loc_stimLA | -0.622877246 | -1.3220944 | 0.07870576 | 1.422310e-03 |
| 12 | RV | loc_stimLV | -0.175692036 | -0.8070004 | 0.45670750 | 4.382634e-04 |
| 13 | RV | loc_stimRA | -0.535687639 | -1.1715584 | 0.10106017 | 4.286051e-04 |

What I need is a table of this style:

| loc_stim_column |  | RA | LA | RV | LV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NSR | logVelocity | -0.502600888 | ... | ... | ... |
|  | conficence_upper | -0.17987440 | ... | ... | ... |
|  | confidence_lower | -0.8253034 | ... | ... | ... |
|  | p_value | 4.045130e-02 | ... | ... | ... |
| loc_stimRA | logVelocity | -0.691259575 | ... | ... | ... |
|  | conficence_upper | -0.30230958 | ... | ... | ... |
|  | confidence_lower | -1.0801617 | ... | ... | ... |
|  | p_value | 2.582846e-08 | ... | ... | ... |
| loc_stimLA | logVelocity | -0.691259575 | ... | ... | ... |
|  | conficence_upper | 0.36848580 | ... | ... | ... |
|  | confidence_lower | -0.4379126 | ... | ... | ... |
|  | p_value | 2.084996e-29 | ... | ... | ... |
| loc_stimRV | logVelocity | NA | ... | ... | ... |
|  | conficence_upper | NA | ... | ... | ... |
|  | confidence_lower | NA | ... | ... | ... |
|  | p_value | NA | ... | ... | ... |
| loc_stimLV | logVelocity | NA | ... | ... | ... |
|  | conficence_upper | NA | ... | ... | ... |
|  | confidence_lower | NA | ... | ... | ... |
|  | p_value | NA | ... | ... | ... |

How can I do that?

This is a code for a data frame to try out:

```
loc_map_column <- c("RA","RA","RA","LV","LV","LV","LV","LA","LA","RV","RV","RV","RV")
loc_stim_column <- c("NSR","loc_stimLA","loc_stimRA","NSR","loc_stimLV","loc_stimRA","loc_stimRV","NSR","loc_stimRA","NSR","loc_stimLA","loc_stimLV","loc_stimRA")
logVelocity <- c(-0.502600888,-0.034630279,-0.691259575,-0.182731047,-0.236928272, -0.913238563,-0.042520352,0.007310606,-0.340983839,-0.351529452,-0.622877246,-0.175692036,-0.535687639)
confidence_lower <- c(0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.4, 0.22, 0.11, 0.33, 0.44, 0.63, 0.133, 0.311, 0.01, 0.001)
confidence_upper <- c(0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.4, 0.22, 0.11, 0.33, 0.44, 0.63, 0.133, 0.311, 0.01, 0.001)
p_value <- c(0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.4, 0.22, 0.11, 0.33, 0.44, 0.63, 0.133, 0.311, 0.01, 0.001)

summarydf <- data.frame(loc_map_column, loc_stim_column, logVelocity, confidence_lower, confidence_upper, p_value)
```

Comment: So you want that new column for `RA`, `LV`, `LA` be a mean value for each variable or one column for each one as `RA_1`, `RA_2` .... and so on?

Comment: No, actually it's just another order of the existing values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the data you've provided, we can do this in two steps with the `tidyr` library.

```
library(tidyr)
```

The first step is to make the data longer, we do this with the function `pivot_longer`, selecting to put all of the numerical columns into one column with the function `where`:

```
longer <- pivot_longer(summarydf, cols = where(is.numeric), names_to = 'measure')
longer
```

This gives us:

```
# A tibble: 52 x 4
   loc_map_column loc_stim_column measure            value
   <chr>          <chr>           <chr>              <dbl>
 1 RA             NSR             logVelocity      -0.503 
 2 RA             NSR             confidence_lower  0.2   
 3 RA             NSR             confidence_upper  0.2   
 4 RA             NSR             p_value           0.2   
 5 RA             loc_stimLA      logVelocity      -0.0346
 6 RA             loc_stimLA      confidence_lower  0.3   
 7 RA             loc_stimLA      confidence_upper  0.3   
 8 RA             loc_stimLA      p_value           0.3   
 9 RA             loc_stimRA      logVelocity      -0.691 
10 RA             loc_stimRA      confidence_lower  0.1   
# ... with 42 more rows
```

We now need to go wider again, we use the function `pivot_wider`. We want that the column `loc_map_column` become the names of the numeric columns. With the previous step all of the numeric columns were mapped to a column called '`value`'

```
pivot_wider(longer,  names_from = loc_map_column, values_from = value)
```

We can wrap these two steps into one with the pipe operator (`%>%`) to get

```
summarydf %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = where(is.numeric), names_to = 'measure') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = loc_map_column, values_from = value)
```

Which gives the output

```
# A tibble: 24 x 6
   loc_stim_column measure               RA     LV       LA     RV
   <chr>           <chr>              <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 NSR             logVelocity      -0.503  -0.183  0.00731 -0.352
 2 NSR             confidence_lower  0.2     0.4    0.44     0.133
 3 NSR             confidence_upper  0.2     0.4    0.44     0.133
 4 NSR             p_value           0.2     0.4    0.44     0.133
 5 loc_stimLA      logVelocity      -0.0346 NA     NA       -0.623
 6 loc_stimLA      confidence_lower  0.3    NA     NA        0.311
 7 loc_stimLA      confidence_upper  0.3    NA     NA        0.311
 8 loc_stimLA      p_value           0.3    NA     NA        0.311
 9 loc_stimRA      logVelocity      -0.691  -0.913 NA       -0.536
10 loc_stimRA      confidence_lower  0.1     0.11  NA        0.001
# ... with 14 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This helps a lot.
But why are the values rounded after the procedure?

And how can i change the order of the loc_stim and loc_map columns?

Comment: When I used your code R told me to add all_of(loc_map_column), which I did:

```summarydf %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = where(is.numeric), names_to = 'measure') %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = all_of(loc_map_column), values_from = value)```

But unfortunately, it still doesn't work. I get the error message:
Error in `stop_subscript()`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Columns `RA`, `RA`, `RA`, `LV`, `LV`, etc. don't exist.

Comment: The values just appear rounded for printing. The true values are still there. [This](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/articles/numbers.html) has some tips.

Comment: Did it "tell" you to use it or "suggest" using `all_of`? I would not use that, as this would make R look for columns with values in the vector `loc_map_column`. You get the error because you have a vector call `loc_map_column` in your workspace. Can you do `rm(loc_map_column)` and run again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's a way to do it clearer, but this code work to accomplish what you're looking for. You can try something like this

```
data <- data.frame(a = c(1:13),
                   loc_map_column = c("RA","RA","RA","LV","LV","LV","LV",
                                      "LA","LA","RV","RV","RV","RV"),
                   loc_stim_column = c("NSR","loc_stimLA","loc_stimRA","NSR",
                                       "loc_stimLV","loc_stimRA","loc_stimRV","NSR",
                                       "loc_stimRA","NSR","loc_stimLA","loc_stimLV",
                                       "loc_stimRA"),
                   logVelocity = c(-0.502600888,-0.034630279,-0.691259575,-0.182731047,
                                   -0.236928272,-0.913238563,-0.042520352,0.007310606,
                                   -0.340983839,-0.351529452,-0.622877246,-0.175692036,
                                   -0.535687639),
                   confidence_lower = c(-0.8253034,-0.034630279,-0.691259575,-0.182731047,
                                        -0.236928272,-0.913238563,-0.042520352,0.007310606,
                                        -0.340983839,-0.351529452,-0.622877246,-0.175692036,
                                        -0.535687639),
                   confidence_upper = c(-0.1798744,0.3684858,-0.30230958,0.46092692,
                                        0.53562934,-0.13692249,0.77911468,0.32826335,
                                        0.09108281,0.18298935,0.07870576,0.4567075,
                                        0.10106017),
                   p_value = c(0.0404513,2.084996E-29,0.00000002582846,0.5829759,
                               0.4102663,2.867447E-27,0.1212858,0.9650069,
                               0.000000001413686,0.2710587,0.00142231,0.0004382634,
                               0.0004286051))
data <- data[,-1]


dtalogV <- data %>% group_by(loc_stim_column) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = loc_map_column,values_from = logVelocity,
              id_cols = loc_stim_column)
dtaconfL <- data %>% group_by(loc_stim_column) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = loc_map_column,values_from = confidence_lower,
              id_cols = loc_stim_column)
dtaconfU <- data %>% group_by(loc_stim_column) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = loc_map_column,values_from = confidence_upper,
              id_cols = loc_stim_column)
dtaPval <- data %>% group_by(loc_stim_column) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = loc_map_column,values_from = p_value,
              id_cols = loc_stim_column)

varnames <- c(rep("logVelocity",length(dtalogV)),rep("confidence_lower",length(dtaconfU)),
                  rep("confidence_upper",length(dtaPval)),rep("p_value",length(dtaconfL)))


databind <-  rbind(dtalogV,dtaconfL,dtaconfU,dtaPval)
final <- data.frame(databind,varnames=varnames)
final <- final[,c(1,6,2:5)]
```